# Write JTextField value into ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, jframe

Hello i can not write the JTextField's value to the ArrayList in another class the error is "...String can not be converted to Object" how can i fix it?
here is the arraylist class

```
public class MemberList
{
    private ArrayList < Member> members;

    /**
     * Create a Member. 
     */
    public MemberList()
    {
        members = new ArrayList < Member>();
    }

    /**
     * Add a member to this member list.
     * @param member the member to be added
     */
    public void addMember(Member member)
    {
        members.add(member);
    }
}
```

and the GUI

```
 public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField jtFName, jtLName, jtMemberNo;
    private int nextMemNo;
    private MemberList members;
    private JFrame frame;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        members = new MemberList();

        if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("Add Member")) {
            if (jtLName.getText().equals("") && (jtFName.getText().equals(""))) {
                jtMember.setText("No names");
            } else if (jtFName.getText().equals("")) {
                jtMember.setText("No first name");
            } else if (jtLName.getText().equals("")) {
                jtMember.setText("No last name");
            } else if (!jtLName.getText().equals("") && (!jtFName.getText().equals(""))) {
                btnOne.setText("Confirm");

                String fName = jtFName.getText();
                String memNo = "1";
                String lName = jtLName.getText();
                members.addMember(member);

            }

        } else if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("No. of Members")) {
            btnTwo.setText("Clear Number");
            jlbMember.setVisible(true);

        } else if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("Clear Number")) {
            jtFName.setText("");
            jtLName.setText("");
        } else if (evt.getActionCommand().equals("Quit")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

What do i need to do to  add jtFName in the ArrayList?
Sorry for the bad editing and thanks

Comment: Create an instance of `Member` class and set the values. Then you can add them to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new instance of your Member class and pass it to your addMember method. For example

```
Member member = new Member(fName, lName); //replace with your actual constructor logic
members.addMember(member);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your List `members` contains object of type `Member` not of type `String`

Either you make that your List contains String like:
`members = new ArrayList<String>();`

Or you make a constructor for your `Member` class in which you pas the String to the object and add the new Object to the List like:

```
public class Member{
  private String name;

  public Member(String name){ //create constructor with String argument
    this.name = name;
  }
}

members.addMember(new Member(name)) //add new Member to list
```

I can't see your Member class but when I look at your code I think it has a fName, lName and memNo. So in your program the constructor will look like:

```
public class Member{
  private String fName;
  private String lName;
  private String memNo;

  public Member(String fNamen, String lName, String memNo){ //create constructor with String arguments
    this.fName= fName;
    this.lName= lName;
    this.memNo= memNo;
  }
}
```

And add it to the List like:

```
members.addMember(new Member(fName, lName, memNo));
```